# Where do packages installed with DNF get stored?

Tags: fedora, package-management, packages, dnf

With APT (Ubuntu), downloaded packages are stored at:

```
/var/cache/apt/archives
```

Where does DNF (Fedora) store downloaded packages?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

DNF stores downloaded packages and metadata in `/var/cache/dnf`, in various per-repository subdirectories.

By default, after a successful installation, the packages are removed. You can change this behavior with `keepcache` in `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`.

Note that PackageKit — in use on Fedora Workstation by default — puts packages in `/var/cache/PackageKit`, so you can get duplicates. Harmonizing this is work in progress.

Comment: Quick find packages `find /var/cache/dnf -name '*.rpm'`

Comment: Do you know where is the cache for the user stored? E.g. if you run `dnf repoquery` without root. I was unable to find this in the dnf documentation. It says: *DNF uses a separate cache for each user under which it executes. The cache for the root user is called the system cache. This switch allows a regular user read-only access to the system cache, which usually is more fresh than the user’s and thus he does not have to wait for metadata sync.*

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't - once a package is installed the downloaded `rpm` file is not normally kept.

The file will be in the cache (in `/var/cache/dnf`) briefly but once it has been successfully installed that will be removed.